# Why won't changes be reflected in Wordpress site when syncing staging to production?

Tags: wordpress, debugging

I've made some slight CSS changes to my website in staging via **Enfold Child > General Styling > Quick CSS** but the problem's that whenever I try to sync my staging site into production (even the checkbox being checked to overwrite content), it says it went through successfully but when I check my production site, it still has the same old CSS that I indeed changed up in **Quick CSS**.

Anyone know what the problem might be?  Image's attached for reference.

[image]

Comment: When you say "check the production site" do you mean the frontend, or the WP backend, both?

Comment: does your site have caching plugins installed like for example Litespeed? because if so, then you might need to purge all your caches there to see results